# dojox.grid.enchancegrid delete row, rows deletet from server but not from grid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I have my enchancegrid named `unitsGrid` thats working properly. I can add rows and delete rows, but when I delete rows I get some problem that I cant figure out so rows doesnt disapear from my unitsGrid when deleted. I have been looking at the code for hours now but I cant seem to figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

```
dojo.connect(unitsGrid, "onRowClick", unitsGrid, function(evt, rowIndx, fieldIndx){

            var idx = evt.rowIndex;
            var item = this.getItem(idx);
            var id = unitsGrid.store.getValue(item, "id");

            if(evt.cellIndex == 3) {
                var con = confirm("Är du säker på att du vill radera denna transaktion?");
                if(con == true) {
                    dojo.xhrPost({
                        url: url,
                        content: {
                            id: id
                        },
                        handleAs: "text",
                        load: function(data) {
                            var selectedRows = grid.selection.getSelected();
                            if (selectedRows.length) {
                            // Iterate through the list of selected items.
                            // The current item is available in the variable
                            // "selectedItem" within the following function:
                                dojo.forEach(selectedRows, function(selectedItem) {
                                    if (selectedItem !== null) {
                                        // Delete the item from the data store:
                                        try {
                                            unitsGrid.store.deleteItem(selectedItem);
                                        }
                                        catch(error) {
                                            console.log("Returned error: " + error.message);
                                        }
                                    } // end if
                                }); // end forEach
                            } // end if
                            console.log("Return value: " + data);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }); // end xhrPost
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call dijit.byId('unitsGrid').removeSelectedRows();